# Criterio de Mysql para el orden de Filas

Tags: mysql, .net

Buenas noches espero que me puedan orientar, tengo dos tablas con los siguientes datos:

(Tabla Cliente)

```
clienteid  nombre   direccion  telefono  email   
---------  -------  ---------  --------  --------
001        gallo                                 
002        salcedo                               
003        paul                                  
41422102   sistema
```

(Tabla Movimiento)

```
movimientoid  fecha       cuentaid  clienteid  monto       tipo  descripcion        
------------  ----------  --------  ---------  --------  ------  -------------------
           1  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  41422102   10000.00       1  Saldo Inicial      
           2  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  003        5000.00       -1  Compra Al Contado  
           3  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  003        100.00        -1  Compra Al Contado  
           4  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  41422102   100.00        -1  Compra Al Contado
```

Realizo una consulta con las dos tablas y tengo datos ordenados:

```
SET @dispo=0;
SELECT movimientoId, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha, descripcion, cliente.clienteid 
IF(tipo=1, monto, NULL) deposito, IF(tipo=-1, monto, NULL) retiro,
IF(tipo=1,@dispo:=@dispo + monto,@dispo:=@dispo - monto) disponible FROM movimiento
 WHERE movimiento.cuentaid='CAJA-001' AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01';

movimientoId  fecha     descripcion        clienteid  deposito  retiro   disponible  
------------  --------  -----------------  --------  ---------  -------  ------------
           1  01/11/18  Saldo Inicial      41422102   10000.00  (NULL)   10000.00    
           2  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  003        (NULL)    5000.00  5000.00     
           3  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  003        (NULL)    100.00   4900.00     
           4  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  41422102   (NULL)    100.00   4800.00
```

Ahora quiero incluir el `nombre` del cliente en lugar del `clienteId`, pero es aquí donde la consulta me devuelve registros desordenados:

```
SET @dispo=0;
SELECT movimientoId, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha, descripcion, nombre,
IF(tipo=1, monto, NULL) deposito, IF(tipo=-1, monto, NULL) retiro,
IF(tipo=1,@dispo:=@dispo + monto,@dispo:=@dispo - monto) disponible 
FROM movimiento INNER JOIN cliente ON movimiento.clienteid=cliente.clienteid
  WHERE movimiento.cuentaid='CAJA-001' AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01';

movimientoId  fecha     descripcion        nombre   deposito  retiro   disponible  
------------  --------  -----------------  -------  --------  -------  ------------
           2  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  paul     (NULL)    5000.00  -5000.00    
           3  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  paul     (NULL)    100.00   -5100.00    
           1  01/11/18  Saldo Inicial      sistema  10000.00  (NULL)   4900.00     
           4  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  sistema  (NULL)    100.00   4800.00
```

**Desordenado** por la columna `MovimientoId` o al menos eso pensé, ya que pude darme cuenta que los registros se ordenaban según la `PK` de la tabla cliente `clienteId`. Ya me explicaron que la ordenación de los registros por default depende del motor, lo hice con `ORDER BY movimientoId` y si sale en orden pero los resultado de la columna `depósito`, `retiro` y `disponible` se calculan mal. De que forma puede ser mi consulta? Gracias. PD: el campo ´clienteid´ en ambas tablas es de tipo VARCHAR(11) aunque lo cambie a `int` y no cambio los resultados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El estándar SQL define que, si no se indica explicitamente como parte de la consulta, el orden de los resultados es *aleatorio*, en el sentido que el motor es libre de *elegir* el orden en el que devolverá los registros de la consulta.

En efecto, en algunos motores se puede llegar a *predecir* el orden en el que una consulta devolverá los resultados, pero esto puede variar en cualquier momento, por ejemplo, si actualizas tu motor a una versión más reciente, si cambia algún parámetro de configuración del motor o si utilizas el mismo motor en un sistema operativo distinto.

Incluso puede llegar a cambiar de acuerdo a las condiciones de los propios datos, pues la mayoría de motores, por ejemplo, utilizarán información estadística sobre los datos para elegir el mejor plan de ejecución y, creeme, este plan de ejecución será el que determinará el orden de los datos.

Por eso es que, al cambiar alguna condición, incluir una nueva tabla en el `join`, o cambiar la lista de columnas, ya tu has experimentado una variación en el orden de los resultados, lo cual es correcto de acuerdo a la especificación.

Por eso, si tu requieres de los datos en un orden particular, existe la clausula `order by`. Con esta, tu indicas exactamente en qué orden quieres que el motor devuelva los datos, utilizando tantas columnas o expresiones como sea necesario para obtener el orden exacto que buscas. También puedes ordenar ascendentemente (`asc`), que es el *default*, o descententemente (`desc`).

Por ejemplo.

```
select *
  from tabla
 order by columna1, columna2, columna3;

select *
  from tabla
 order by columna1 asc, columna2 + columna3 desc;

select *
  from tabla
 order by columna1 asc, substring(columna2, 1, 2) desc
        , case when columna3 = 1 then columna4 else columna5 end desc;
```

---

**Edición**

Veo que lo que buscas no solo es *ordenar*, sino que el cálculo del `disponible` sea correcto.

Primero explico que, está *fallando* porque el cálculo ocurre antes de la ordenación.

La manera correcta de resolver esto, en el estándar, es utilizar *funciones de ventana*, pero estas no están disponibles hasta versiones recientes de *mysql* (creo que a partir de la 8, pero no estoy seguro).

```
SELECT   movimientoId
       , DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha
       , descripcion
       , nombre
       , IF(tipo=1, monto, NULL) deposito
       , IF(tipo=-1, monto, NULL) retiro
       , sum(monto * tipo) over (order by movimientoId rows between unbounded preceding and current row) disponible
  FROM movimiento 
       INNER JOIN cliente ON movimiento.clienteid = cliente.clienteid
 WHERE movimiento.cuentaid = 'CAJA-001' 
   AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01'
 order by movimientoId
```

Ahora, si utilizas una versión anterior, no tengo *mysql* a mano para probar, pero supongo que valiéndome de que este <del>extraño</del> motor soporta poner una clausula `order by` dentro de los sub-queries, que generalmente ignora, excepto si pones una clausula `limit`, diría que la solución está en:

- Poner la consulta que trae los datos dentro de una sub-consulta, sin el cálculo del disponible, pero con una clausula `order by`
- Realizar una consulta sobre la sub-consulta anterior, y aprovechando que nos devuelve el resultado ordenado, sobre esta realizar el cálculo (no hay garantía que funcione, ni que la sintaxis sea correcta).

Usala por tu cuenta y riesgo:

```
SET @dispo=0;
select   x.*
       , @dispo := @dispo + coalesce(deposito, 0) - coalesce(retiro, 0) disponible
  from (SELECT   movimientoId
               , DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha
               , descripcion
               , nombre
               , IF(tipo=1, monto, NULL) deposito
               , IF(tipo=-1, monto, NULL) retiro
          FROM movimiento 
               INNER JOIN cliente ON movimiento.clienteid = cliente.clienteid
         WHERE movimiento.cuentaid = 'CAJA-001' 
           AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01'
         order by movimientoId
         limit 25000
        ) as X
```

Comment: Gracias @jachGuate por tu ayuda, como seria la consulta, yo hice:

 SET @dispo=0;  
 SELECT movimientoId, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha, descripcion, nombre, 
 IF(tipo=1,monto,NULL) deposito, IF(tipo=-1,monto,NULL) retiro,
 IF(tipo=1,@dispo:=@dispo + monto,@dispo:=@dispo - monto) disponible FROM 
  (SELECT movimientoId, fecha, descripcion,cliente.nombre, monto , tipo FROM movimiento INNER JOIN cliente
  ON movimiento.`clienteid` = cliente.`clienteId`
  WHERE movimiento.cuentaId='caja01' AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2018-12-07' ORDER BY movimientoid) tmp;

Comment: @Paul, edité mi respuesta.

Comment: la versión mysql q tengo no tiene funciones de ventana; pero lo buscare para aprender, la ultima consulta que pusiste me da los resultados esperados, igual como lo puse en el comentario. Antes tenia estas tablas y me daban los resultados que quería; pero cambie el nombre de los campos, agregue otros y cambio el resultado tal como dijiste que pasaría, no quiero hacer doble select lo digo por la subconsulta pero veo que es necesario no quiero llevarme sorpresas después. Mysql 8  tiene las funciones de ventana creo q la instalare para aprender y practicar, te AGRADEZCO MUCHO LA AYUDA

Comment: usando tu ejemplo si quiero ordenar por fecha ´ORDER BY fecha´ no trabaja correctamente debe ser por el DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Si almacenas la fecha como `date` no debieras tener mayor problema si haces el `order by` dentro de la sub-consulta. Si hay varios registros de la misma `fecha`, asegurate de incluir un campo adicional para que el orden sea _correcto_.